# how to skip some rules and continue to match other rules if needed on bison?

Tags: bison, yacc

I am having trouble with this Bison program. how to add a switch about a rule.

Here is an example:

```
//flex file
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
%%
[0-9]+     { return SNUM; }
[a-zA-Z]+  { return STR; }
[()\n]     { return yytext[0];}
.          { return 0; /* end when meet everything else */ }
%%

int yywrap(void) { 
    return 1;
}


//bison file
%{
#include <stdio.h>
void yyerror(const char* msg) {}
%}

%token STR
%token SNUM

%left '(' ')'

%%

S    :   STMT           { printf("It's a stmt\n");}
     |   FUC            { printf("It's a FUCTION\n"); }     
     ;
FUC  :   STR '(' STR ')' '\n' {}
     |   STR '(' SNUM ')' '\n' {}
     ;
STMT :   SNUM '(' SNUM ')'  '\n'     {}
     ;
%%
int main() {
    return yyparse();
}
```

And now, I want to add a rule that sometimes SNUM is a function name, sometimes it's not. the rule maybe like:

```
FUC  :   STR '(' STR ')' '\n' {}
     |   STR '(' SNUM ')' '\n' {}
     if(ok){
     |   SNUM '(' SNUM ')' '\n' {}
     }
     ;
```

`ok` is globle variable. when input "123(123)", if `ok` is true, the output will be "It's function", otherwise "stmt".
How to achieve this.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask bison to produce a [GLR parser](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#GLR-Parsers), then you can guard productions with a [semantic predicate](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Semantic-Predicates), which is an action which can control whether or not a rule is considered at a particular moment in a parse. This feature cannot be implemented in an LALR(1) parser, so there is no equivalent with a default configuration.

I don't know if that serves your need, since you don't explain what problem you are actually attempting to solve. But it's possible that this is a solution.

There are a variety of things which you need to take into account when building GLR parsers, particularly if your semantic actions have side effects; please read the documentation carefully.

Comment: thanks for your time. sorry, I didn't make myself clear. I add a new example.  How to achieve this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I thought of a method, but it's not good and lovely. 
- make a copy of bison;
- add the rule; 
- bison the two files with "-p" to generote two **parse();
- run twice, each parse() once;

Comment: @Jack: Seems like the GLR solution would be simpler and cleaner. If it's not an appropriate solution, then probably I don't really understand what you need. (There is also possibly a solution which involves a small change to your scanner. But since I don't know what exactly you're trying to do, I didn't want to suggest it.)